# How can I share variables between If statements?

Tags: java

The problem is that I need to share variables between `if` statements without them going out of scope. This is what I've written so far:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GrossPay2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // declare an object that will display two decimal digits
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        
        // declare an object that will display the current date
        Date myDate = new Date();
        String myDateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat dtToday = new SimpleDateFormat(myDateFormat);
        System.out.println("Today's Date is: " + dtToday.format(myDate));
        
        // display the name of the programmer
        System.out.println("Programmer: John Doe");
        
        //display a dummy value to show that two decimals are obtained
        System.out.println("Test amount: " + nf.format(2.575));
        
        // taking inputs
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of items produced");
        int numItems = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for a flat rate or 2 for a differential rate");
        int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        // doing taxes
        double grossPay = numItems * 7.5;
        double medicareTax = grossPay * .0145;
        double ficaTax = grossPay * .062;
        double federalTax = grossPay * .25;
        
        // if rate is flat
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            double taxes = medicareTax + ficaTax + federalTax;
            double netPay = grossPay - taxes;
            Output(name, numItems, medicareTax, ficaTax, federalTax, netPay);
        }
        
        double total;
        double payRate1;
        double payRate2;
        double payRate3;
        double payRate4;
        int remainder;
        
        // if rate is differential
        if(choice == 2)
        {
            if(numItems >= 1 && numItems <= 112 )
            {
                payRate1 = (112 - numItems) * 7.15;
                remainder = 112-numItems;
                total = payRate1;
                System.out.println("test1");
            }
            else if(numItems >= 113 && numItems <= 150)
            {
                payRate2 = (150 - numItems) * 7.45;
                remainder = 150 - numItems;
                total = payRate1 + payRate2;
                System.out.println("test2");
            }
            else if(numItems >= 151 && numItems <= 217)
            {
                payRate3 = (217 - numItems) * 7.95;
                remainder = 217 - numItems;
                total = payRate1 + payRate2 + payRate3;
                System.out.println("test3");
            }
            else if(numItems > 217)
            {
                payRate4 = (numItems - 217) * 8.40;
                total = payRate1 + payRate2 + payRate3 + payRate4;
                System.out.println("test4");
            }
        }
        }
    
    public static void Output(String Name, int Items, double Medicare, double Fica, double Federal, double Net)
    {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println("\n\nEmployee name: " + Name);
        System.out.println("Items produced: " + Items);
        System.out.println("Medicare tax: " + nf.format(Medicare));
        System.out.println("FICA tax: " + Fica);
        System.out.println("Federal tax: " + Federal);
        System.out.println("Net pay: " + Net);
    }
    
    
}
```

Basically my payRate variables go out of scope. I need to code something like the U.S. tax system, but replaced with commission for items sold I.E, first 112 items sold have a different rate than the next 40, and so on. Running a test with a number like 100 returns Test1. Anything above 112 does not return Test2 or the other ones.

What I mean by "sharing" is that I want payRate1 from the 1-112 range to carry over to the 113-151 range, so that I can add it to payRate2 to create a total, then carry on payRate2 to 151-217 range, add it to payRate3, and finally to the 217+ range, to add all of them together with payRate4.

If anyone has any tips for printing choice 2, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It is unclear what you are asking and what you mean by "sharing". Please add a more detailed description of what you want to do and the example output you want from example inputs.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply different factors to parts of the total?

Something like 7 * 112 first elements + 7.5 * 38 more elements + ...

If so, the problem is the else if structure, I recommend:

```
nItems1 = Math.min(112, numItems);
nItems2 = Math.min(38, numItems - 112);
nItems3 = Math.min(..., numItems - 150);
total = nItems1 * rate1 + nItems2 * rate2 + ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
...
double payRate1 = (112 - numItems) * 7.15;
double payRate2 = (150 - numItems) * 7.45;
double payRate3 = (217 - numItems) * 7.95;
double payRate4 = (numItems - 217) * 8.40;

if(numItems >= 1 && numItems <= 112 )
{
    remainder = 112-numItems;
    total = payRate1;
    System.out.println("test1");
}
else if(numItems >= 113 && numItems <= 150)
{
    remainder = 150 - numItems;
    total = payRate1 + payRate2;
    System.out.println("test2");
}
else if(numItems >= 151 && numItems <= 217)
{
    remainder = 217 - numItems;
    total = payRate1 + payRate2 + payRate3;
    System.out.println("test3");
}
else if(numItems > 217)
{
    total = payRate1 + payRate2 + payRate3 + payRate4;
    System.out.println("test4");
}
```

<sup>based only on title "How can I share variables between If statements?"  - the code proposed here will generate negative values (I'm not a tax expert, but that probably is not correct)

I also wonder if `payRate1` (and `total`) is really intended to be zero if `numItems == 112`?</sup>